# Xamarin.Forms Listview with 2 line label?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, monotouch.dialog

I'm converting a **MonoTouch.Dialog** app to **Xamarin.Forms**.

I have a Cell in a ListView and that has a "Detail" line that should be 2 lines long, and should truncate the tail after that.

```
        var lblDetail = new Label
        {
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
            Text = "a really long string that should show 2 lines then ..."
        };
```

How do I set something like, "Lines = 2"

Comment: You probably need to create a custom cell.  XF Labs has an ExtendedTextCell - it may do what you need, the documentation is sparse so its hard to tell.

Comment: is my answer help you?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Because it solved mine ;)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You might want to customize ListView:

```
    <ListView x:Name="ListMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding _YourItems_}" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding _YourText_}" TextColor="Black" />
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

even if text not fit one line, it will wrap automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with a custom renderer

This is my xaml (in my pcl project)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
          <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
            <customRenderers:MultiLineLabel Text="{Binding Summary}"
                                            Grid.Column="1"/>
          </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

This is my `MultiLineLabel` class

```
public class MultiLineLabel : Label
    {
    }
```

This is the renderer for iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MultiLineLabel), typeof(MultiLineLabelRenderer))]
namespace NameSpace.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class MultiLineLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
                Control.Lines = 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to achieve this same thing in `Android` any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

the following code working fine for me :)

```
 UserNotesListView = new ListView() {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HasUnevenRows=true,
                ItemsSource=//upon your bussiess
            };

            DataTemplate dt=new DataTemplate(()=>
                {
                    var LabelText = new Label();
                    LabelText.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("note"));
                    return new ViewCell { View = LabelText };
            });
            UserNotesListView.ItemTemplate = dt;
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Children=
                {
                    UserNotesListView
                }
            };
```